# 404 error when navigating to image file NGINX

Tags: image, nginx, server

I cannot navigate to an image file. When I try to visit my page at http://example.com/public/images/header.png I receive a 404 error.

I made sure the image exists in /var/www/example.com/public/images/ folder but I am still receiving a 404 error when trying to access the above link. Here is my NGINX server block config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/example.com/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /images/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/public/images/;
        add_header  Cache-control "public";
        access_log  off;
        expires 90d;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
    }

    include /var/www/example.com/.nginx.conf;
}
```

As you can see my site is being served out of the /public folder. I have a Flarum forum that I can access at example.com. I want to be able to serve an image on the forum as a background but I cannot even get the server to simply display the image at example.com/public/images/header.png. Can someone please explain to me what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of `/var/www/streetscramblers.com/.nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `root` is set to `/var/www/example.com/public`, so why would you expect having an image accessible at `http://example.com/public/images/header.png` ?

The link where it is accessible would be `http://example.com/images/header.png`.

The last published config by you contains invalid `alias` in images location. It should be simple, without `alias`:

```
location /images/ {
    add_header  Cache-control "public";
    access_log  off;
    expires 90d;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by redirecting all http requests to https and by adjusting the config.php(part of Flarum core) file to include https:// instead of http:// in the domain url. Here are the newly edited server block and config.php file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always; 

    root /var/www/example.com/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /images/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/public/images/;
        add_header  Cache-control "public";
        access_log  off;
        expires 90d;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
    }

    include /var/www/example.com/.nginx.conf;
}
```

config.php:

```
<?php return array (
  'debug' => true,
  'database' => 
  array (
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 3306,
    'database' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
  ),
  'url' => 'https://example.com',
  'paths' => 
  array (
    'api' => 'api',
    'admin' => 'admin',
  ),
);
```